# Linux: URL removes slash when trying to access via https

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, ssl

I installed a linux server with Ubuntu.
Installed the certificate files.
Created a directory under /var/www/ with my domain name and public html
/var/www/domain_name/public_html/

In the default-ssl.conf file i have the following and the location of my ssl files.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.domain
        ServerName domain.domain

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain_name/public_html/
```

When I browse to the page https://domainname it opens the right way.
When I browse to the page https://domainname/subfolder/index.php it opens also.

But when I try to access https://domainname/phpmyadmin it removes the slash and makes the URL https://domainnamephpmyadmin.

I can access the phpmyadmin without https.

Where did I forgot something?

Extra info:
When I browse to: https://domainname/phpmyadmin/?SID it works. For what is ?SID?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I forced the SSL in the config.inc.php file under et/phpmyadmin/

```
$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;
```

restart apache and reload apache config

Comment: `$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;` is definitely not an Apache configuration statement. It's totally unclear what you are talkung about.

Comment: @blafasel you are right I deleted this statement after some research